# Python- Convert dictionary to dictionary with list value

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanna convert dictionary to dictionary with list value

I wanna convert :

```
 f= {24149423: 59, 22621293.0: 367562.0, 24144369.0: 405017.0, 22662739.0: 276484.0, 22470388.0: 410315.0, 22624054.0: 398444.0, 22614201.0: 380106.0, 22564857.0: 90756.0, 22619259.0: 382386.0, 22692381.0: 388392.0}
```

to dictionary with list value

```
b =  {90756.0: [22564857.0], 388392.0: [22692381.0], 367562.0: [22621293.0], 410315.0: [22470388.0], 398444.0: [22624054.0], 382386.0: [22619259.0], 405017.0: [24144369.0], 276484.0: [22662739.0], 59: [24149423], 380106.0: [22614201.0]}
```

I try to write it this way:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

b = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in sorted(f.iteritems()):
    b[value].append(key)
```

I used map as well.

```
b = map(lambda k, v: f.update({k: v}), keys, values)
```

But none of these work.

Comment: That `defaultdict` code works for me.

Comment: "But none of these work." ... because I get **results X** and I was expecting to see **results Y**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [dict comprehension](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), like this:

```
b = { v: [k] for k,v in f.items() }
```

`[k]` is a one-element list containing the key, `v` is the value, which now plays the rold of the key in the resulting dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

```
for key in f.keys():
    f[key] = [f[key]]
```

Also Works ....

Answer (score 0):

```
f= {24149423: 59, 22621293.0: 367562.0, 24144369.0: 405017.0, 22662739.0: 276484.0, 22470388.0: 410315.0, 22624054.0: 398444.0, 22614201.0: 380106.0, 22564857.0: 90756.0, 22619259.0: 382386.0, 22692381.0: 388392.0}
new_f = {x:[f[x]] for x in f}
```

Using dict comprehension you can edit it pretty fast.